# Multiple screen view on laptop display

Tags: graphics, screen-resolution, display, bios

First I dont know wheather this is right place to ask such question.

My laptop displays multiple screen on booting. I googled about this but I am unable to find the solution. came across this type of dysfunction on many laptops screen.

I cant figure out whether it is a screen problem/ hardware problem/ graphic card problem or its a bios problem.

I would really appreciate if anyone can direct me towards correct solution.

Answer (score -3):

Following steps will help zero down

- Enter Safe mode ( F8 in most ) and then see if its there. If it's gone then there's a problem likely with the graphics driver
- Try to download the latest Chipset drivers from Intel or AMD Site depending on your Graphics card. Intel has a chipset detect utility that will pull up the latest drivers for all intel h/w on the pc
- If you see this just on the desktop ( and not other apps like browser ) - it because the desktop background image is tiled vs Centered / stretched.  In that case change it to centered.
- Uninstall graphics driver and see if the multiple images disappear. You will not see high res image without driver but it will rule out card failure vs improper driver